# Turning a list of dictionaries into a single larger dictionary

Tags: python

Maybe this is a simple question, but I've been scratching my head on it.

How do I turn a list of several dictionaries into a single dictionary containing all values?

This is what I mean:

```
input_list = [
    {'fruit': 'banana',
     'color1': ''},
    {'vegetable': 'tomato',
     'color2': ''},
    {'dessert': 'ice cream',
     'taste': ''}
]

desired_output = {
    'fruit': 'banana',
    'color1': '',
    'vegetable': 'tomato',
    'color2': '',
    'dessert': 'ice cream',
    'taste': ''
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: @baduker That looks very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
output = {key:value for element in input_list for key, value in element.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'fruit': 'banana',
 'color1': '',
 'vegetable': 'tomato',
 'color2': '',
 'dessert': 'ice cream',
 'taste': ''}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop through the list and use update() method to merge the dictionaries that is all needed to do:

```
desired_output = {}
for d in input_list:
  desired_output.update(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

You can merge [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with the `|` bitwise operator from version `3.9`. chaining them, with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator._or):

### Rough explanation of `functools.reduce`

```
 functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])
```

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value

Here are some examples for functools.reduce:

```
>>> #calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5) which is the sum
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
15
>>> # factorial of 5 using reduce
>>> n = 4
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(1,n+1))
24
```

### Answer

Using `functools.reduce` and `operator._or` here is the code that I come up with:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(operator.or_,list_of_dicts)
pprint.pprint(result)
```

**EDIT**: As @KellyBundy commented, my implementation is `O(n^2)` but using `operator.ior` and the `Optional` initializer parameter, we could make it linear.

Implementation:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(operator.ior,list_of_dicts,{})
pprint(result)
```

#### Output

```
{'fruit': 'banana',
 'color1': '',
 'vegetable': 'tomato',
 'color2': '',
 'dessert': 'ice cream',
 'taste': ''}
```

Comment: Inefficient for long lists, though...

Comment: Could use `ior` with an initial `{}`, that would be linear instead of quadratic.